# Why is firebase not receiving any data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I followed the instructions from the Firebase assistant for Realtime Database, but no data is sent. I connected the app to Firebase and the dependencies are set up correctly.
This is my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

        myRef.setValue("Hello!");
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", "Value is: " + value);
                text.setText(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w("TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The log works and in the console I get a "D/TAG: Value is: Hello!" but when I look in Firebase the database is empty. [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzZSE.png)

Those are the rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added internet permission?

Comment: Can you please try adding a success and a failure listener on setValue ?

Comment: Yes, I added it @Hascher

Comment: @Dharmaraj I added, it does not enter in either success or failure

Comment: Is your onDataChange even triggered?